# Why is only one instance of the OpenGraph show in my activities?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Whenever I use the [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) of facebook to POST  "actions" on an object, I do get a different **id** for each action, but see only one post on facebook. Why is that?

Comment: I think Facebook clubs together you activities. If you happen to do same actions on different objects it will be aggregated together.

Comment: I did create an aggregation, but it doesn't show the different activities. It's as if the OBJECT is actually the URL I am sending. Maybe I am doing something wrong? Maybe I need to create a different URL for each object? But isn't that completely missing out on all the idea of dynamic web pages?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should have a different URL for each og object.  Each og object needs to have different `og:xxxxxx` tags anyway.  Consider these og objects on RottenTomatoes:

http://www.rottentomatoes.com/celebrity/tom_hanks

http://www.rottentomatoes.com/celebrity/meg_ryan

View the source of those pages and you'll see `og:image` and other `og:` tags.

Those are good examples of dynamic web pages as well.

#### To answer your follow-up question in the comments:

You can make `x.php?a=0` a different object than `x.php?a=1` by varying the `<meta>` tags, and it will pass the [FB Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) just fine.

For example, I created these dynamic objects:

http://plooza.com/og/dynamic1.php?obj=0

http://plooza.com/og/dynamic1.php?obj=1

When I enter these og objects/URLs into the Debugger, it scrapes and parses them and recognizes them as different objects because I'm doing this on the webserver:

```
$obj_number = (int)$_REQUEST['obj'];
echo '<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.plooza.com/og/dynamic1.php?obj='.$obj_number.'" />';

switch ($obj_number) {
  case 1:
    $url = 'http://img2.10bestmedia.com/Images/Photos/68906/bar-one-exterior_6_400x400.jpg';
    break;
  default:
    $url = 'http://cdn.ghacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/microsoft-default-manager22.png';
    break;
}
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$url.'" />';
```

Note that I've changed `og:url` and `og:image` based on the value of `obj` in `dynamic1.php?obj=`

When I submit `http://plooza.com/og/dynamic1.php?obj=1` to the Debugger it shows a different `og:image` than when `obj=0`

Comment: My problem is that I have a numerous amount of objects, even endless amount in theory. I need a way to call object.php?image=tomato.jpg&title=tomato to make an object just like you showed with Tom and Meg. Only in this way, the go:url would be just the same (object.php?image=tomato.jpg&title=tomato) and would result in the page I need for Facebook and the user. I am not sure I was clear enough... I figured the URL x.php?a=1 is different than x.php?a=2 so I am still stuck

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your follow-up question.  See updated answer.